# How to make default "Privacy Policy Page" a normal page?

Tags: posts, pages

When you install WordPress it creates a default Privacy Policy page. I would like to make this page be a normal page, but I can't see where to "unset" the Privacy Policy page. I named this page "Company" but as you can see it still says it's the Privacy Policy page. How can I change this?

(I want to repurpose this existing page in order to keep the page IDs sequential and logical for my site.)

[image: privacy-policy-screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log into your wordpress admin area. Go to Settings-> Privacy

[image]

From there, you can either select a different(unsued) page for default privacy policy page or you can create a new one within same page. So change your current privacy page to a different one and you can use it as you wish